# Python 3: How to generate random float (in two decimal places) between 10.00 and 100.00

Tags: python-3.x

I need help generating random float (in two decimal places) between 10.00 and 100.00 And I would like to do it without using the print function.

I tried random.choice(range(10.10, 200.00)) but it does not work, because parameters have to be integers.

random.uniform(1, 10) does not seem to have an option for trimming the decimals.

Comment: `round(random.uniform(10, 100), 2)`

Comment: A lot of times when you're working with floating points like this, it's easier to just sidestep them and use integers to avoid all the issues with them. Your range is equivalent to a range of 1000-10000 with the end result divided by 100.